# FIND_IN_SET sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, find-in-set

I have query like below.

```
SELECT Id, FIND_IN_SET('22', Category ) >0 AS `tot_cat` 
FROM tbl_doctorprofile
```

I am getting result 1 in which row i am getting value '22' else 0..
so result is like below.

```
Id tot_cat
----------
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    0
```

But i want only count of rows which has value 1.

Comment: Show Input data for your query

Answer (score 2):

So just sum the column:

```
SELECT SUM(FIND_IN_SET('22', Category ) >0) AS `tot_cat` 
FROM tbl_doctorprofile
```

or formally a bit better:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('22', Category ) > 0
FROM tbl_doctorprofile
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET('22', Category ) > 0 THEN 1 END) AS `tot_cat` 
FROM tbl_doctorprofile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query it must help you

```
 SELECT COUNT(1) FROM 
(SELECT Id, FIND_IN_SET('22', Category ) >0 AS `tot_cat` 
FROM tbl_doctorprofile ) t WHERE t.tot_cat!=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you want this?

```
SELECT Id, FIND_IN_SET('22', Category ) >0 AS `tot_cat` 
FROM tbl_doctorprofile
HAVING `tot_cat` = 1
```